# Django formset: how to manually add management data to request.POST?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I have use-cases, when a formset does not get rendered in the page. In this case `request.POST` does not contain management data.

How can I manually add missing management data? `request.POST` QueryDict is read only.

As the answer suggests, I used:

```
request_post_copy = request.POST.copy()
if not request_post_copy.has_key('form-TOTAL_FORMS'):
    request_post_copy.update({
        'form-TOTAL_FORMS': 0,
        'form-INITIAL_FORMS': 0,
        'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': 1000,
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the error is that management form data is missing, then management form data IS missing.

Take a look at this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates

In the example they use this to display additional fields:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
```

And if those fields are missing then you get the error you are seeing.

**Edit:**

If you want to add management fields manually to data, then you need to add 3 key/value pairs for fields like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="3" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" />
<input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="3" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" />
<input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" />
```

Do something like this:

```
my_post_dict = request.POST.copy()
my_post_dict['form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = value
my_post_dict['form-INITIAL_FORMS'] = value
my_post_dict['form-MAX_NUM_FORMS'] = value
myformset = MyFormSet(my_post_dict)
```

Comment: Yes, I know that these fields are missing. I need simple check to find out that they are not set or some kind of Formset flag to allow missing management data. I want to know best way to deal with it.

Comment: In that case, its probably best to describe, why you think you cant use request.POST there. Sure it may contain stuff for other forms, but that is not a problem in case of Django unless the fields off different forms have same names.

Comment: I can use request.POST, but cannot use ``or None`` statement to check if management data is missing. I do not post management data and want to create empty formset from the ``request.POST`` data.

Comment: I feel like im missing something here. If you can use request.POST, then use it. If you want to create empty formset from request.POST data, then create it - just add management form data manually. Create copy from request.POST and add missing fields...

Comment: Exactly, I want to know how to copy request.POST and add management data manually. I would appreciate if you would write an answer.